# Appium iOS Do I need to trust WebDriverAgentRunner everytime I run Appium?

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, appium-ios, xcuitest

so I have a free developer account and I'm not sure if that makes any difference. But right now, I have to trust myself as a developer every time I execute Appium on my iPhone for WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner in the Device management settings. Is there anyway around this? Perhaps this is the difference between a free and paid developer membership?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share screenshot of pop you are getting every time?
once you Select your device from XCode, signed it with valid certificate and build on you iPhone should help you. Please follow below steps

1. Right click on Appium Server GUI > Contents > Resources > App > node_modules > appium > node_modules > Appium-webdriver agent
2. Check for WebDriverAgent.XCodeProj
3. Open WebDriverAgent.XCodeProj in XCode
4. If project is not open click on folder icon present on top right corner.
   Click on WebDriverAgent
5. In centre panel > TARGETS Select WebDriverAgentRunner
6. Click on Signing and Capabilities
7. Click on "Team" Drop down to sign in your app
8. You can select existing certificate or new certificate where you have to apple certificate
9. Find WebDriverAgent project on top.
10. select WebDriverAgentRunner from drop down
11. Select targeted device from drop down on which you want to execute test cases
12. Click on "Product" menu
13. Click on "Test"
14. It will install WebDriverAgent on you targeted device
15. Now you can try to launch new session from appium inspector

If this did not solved your problem install some other applicationwith same certificate you are using. Do not remove it from phone till you are testing your targeted app. It will kept your certificate in the phone even if you end your session

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow full manual configuration steps as given below if you are using free developer account.

1. Add your Apple ID to XCode and download the certificate
2. Find WebDriverAgent project,
   here i have given path for both Appium CLI as well as Appium Desktop you can use either path to configure the wda.
   In terminal, execute command:

   ```
   $ where appium or which Appium
   /path/where/installed/bin/appium

   Eg: WebDriverAgent project path for
   Appium CLI:
   /path/where/installed/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent
   Appium Desktop:
   /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent
   ```
3. Navigate to WebDriverAgent project path in terminal and run below command to setup the project

   ```
   mkdir -p Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle
       ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d
   ```
4. Open WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj in Xcode. For both the WebDriverAgentLib and WebDriverAgentRunner targets, select "Automatically manage signing" in the "General" tab, and then select your Development Team. This should also auto select Signing Certificate.
5. Manually change the bundle id for the target by going into the "Build Settings" tab, and changing the "Product Bundle Identifier" from com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner to
   something that Xcode will accept (something really unique!)
6. Command to build the project:

   ```
   xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=<udid>' test
   ```
7. Above command should install WDA on the given UDID of the device. Now manually go to setting and trust the WDA
8. Now try to again build the project with allowProvisioningUpdates flag:

   ```
   xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=<udid>' test -allowProvisioningUpdates
   ```
9. Create session with app using Appium Inspector pointing to CLI server